# Как задать траекторию по площади поверхности сферичного сегмента

Tags: математика, 3d, геометрия

Имеется сфера в пространстве (x, y, z). Плоскостью я отсекаю нужный мне сегмент (по форме как плоско-выпуклая линза). По выпуклой этого сегмента необходимо двигать камеру и для этого необходимо задать траекторию. Наведите на мысль или формулы, которые мне помогут решить задачу.

P.S. Задаю вопрос т.к. может кто сталкивался с этим. Как вариант думаю построить вектор от центра сферы к центру сегмента (вектор длиной = r (сферы)) и относительно его строить вектор такой же длины с указанием угла между векторами.

Comment: В полярных координатах делаете, верно?

Comment: Декатровой, через триг. функции

Answer (score 1):

“Параметрическое уравнение сферы с центром в точке”

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сфера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

Задать свои пределы параметрам на ту часть где отрезали сферу.
Получите координаты камеры A0 от двух параметров.
Сделать вектор  A1 из A0 в точку 0.0.0.
 Сделать вектор  `A2 (x(A0),y(A0),z(A0)+1)`.
Сделать вектор  A3=Кросс продукт A1 на A2 даст  ось для камеры.
Сделать вектор  A4=Кросс продукт A3 на A1 даст еще ось.
Получите 3 оси для камеры вектора A1 A3 A4 дают ориентацию  камеры и центр камеры A0. Нужные нормализовать.